# How to fix 'No OUs found'

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am using the Google Admin SDK - Directory API, I have a successful connection to the API but no OUs are being stored in my array.

Result:

**Getting the OUs in the domain
No OUs found in the domain.**

I tried modifying the code to list the first 10 users instead and it works.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit']

def main():

    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Admin SDK Directory API
    print('Getting the OUs in the domain')
    results = service.orgunits().list(customerId='my_customer').execute()
    ou_list = results.get('orgunits', [])

    if not ou_list:
        print('No OUs found in the domain.')
    else:
        print('OU List:')
        # for ou in ou_list:
        #     print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(ou_list['name'], ou_list['orgUnitPath']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

No error messages are displayed but, OUs are not being stored.

Answer (score 0):

The key is not `orgunits`, it is `orgazinationalUnits`:

```
ou_list = results.get('orgunits', [])
```